# Twisted: Mixing ReconnectingClientFactory with SSL write() raise ssl error frequently

Tags: python, twisted

I'm inheriting `ReconnectingClientFactory` and use SSL connection. We have it all running, but I am getting the following error after a few minute.  Once this error happend, the connection is lost

```
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/hikvision/ezops/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 103, in callWithLogger
    return callWithContext({"system": lp}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/hikvision/ezops/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 86, in callWithContext
    return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/hikvision/ezops/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/hikvision/ezops/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
    return func(*args,**kw)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/local/hikvision/ezops/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 597, in _doReadOrWrite
    why = selectable.doRead()
  File "/usr/local/hikvision/ezops/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 208, in doRead
    return self._dataReceived(data)
  File "/usr/local/hikvision/ezops/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 214, in _dataReceived
    rval = self.protocol.dataReceived(data)
  File "/usr/local/hikvision/ezops/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 430, in dataReceived
    self._flushReceiveBIO()
  File "/usr/local/hikvision/ezops/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 400, in _flushReceiveBIO
    self._flushSendBIO()
  File "/usr/local/hikvision/ezops/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 352, in _flushSendBIO
    bytes = self._tlsConnection.bio_read(2 ** 15)
  File "/usr/local/hikvision/ezops/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1384, in bio_read
    self._handle_bio_errors(self._from_ssl, result)
  File "/usr/local/hikvision/ezops/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1365, in _handle_bio_errors
    _raise_current_error()
  File "/usr/local/hikvision/ezops/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 48, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: []
```

my client code like this:

```
reactor.connectSSL(opscenter_addr, int(opscenter_port), NoahAgentFactory(), ssl.ClientContextFactory())
```

class NoahAgentFactory like this:

```
import logging
import traceback

from OpenSSL import SSL
from twisted.internet import reactor,ssl
from twisted.internet import task
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.internet.protocol import ReconnectingClientFactory
import DataPackageCodecFactory as Codec
from Header import MessageHandlerMap
from Handler import HBReq, DefaultRspHandler
from Util import Connection

logger = logging.getLogger('opsagent')


class NoahAgentProtocol(Protocol):
    t = None
    def connectionMade(self):
        '''
            客户端连接成功之后会自动调用该方法
            :return:
        '''
        self.transport.setTcpKeepAlive(True) # maintain the TCP connection
        self.transport.setTcpNoDelay(True) # allow Nagle algorithm

        # 连接成功后保存连接信息
        Connection.AgentTcpConnection = self
        global t
        logger.info('is already connect to the server')
        self.recv_data_buffer = ''
        # 创建定时的心跳任务,每隔30秒执行一次
        t = task.LoopingCall(HBReq.execute, *[self])
        t.start(30)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        logger.debug("Received Message: %s", repr(data))
        ###code handler packages##########

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        '''
        当客户端连接断开的时候,会自动调用该方法
        :param reason:
        :return:
        '''
        try:
            t.stop()
            # 清空全局链接信息
            Connection.AgentTcpConnection = None
        except:
            logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
        logger.info('Connection is lost and Task stopped,Resaon =>%s', reason)


class NoahAgentFactory(ReconnectingClientFactory):
    def startedConnecting(self, connector):
        logger.info('Started to connect.')

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        logger.info('Connected.')
        logger.info('Resetting reconnection delay')
        self.resetDelay()
        return NoahAgentProtocol()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        logger.info('Lost connection.  Reason:%s', reason)
        self.resetDelay()
        self.retry(connector)
        # ReconnectingClientFactory.clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason)

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        logger.info('Connection failed. Reason:%s', reason)
        self.resetDelay()
        self.retry(connector)
```

Comment: It seems like this may be a bug in Twisted's TLS support.  It would be great to know: the version of Python, the version of Twisted, the version of OpenSSL, the version of cryptography, the version of pyOpenSSL, and what is running on the other side of this connection (a public TLS server, another server you wrote, what TLS implementation it uses, etc).  It would also be *really* nice to have a minimal example that reproduces the problem.  http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not a bug in Twisted's TLS other than a mistake,I send the message not in the main reactor thread,as we know,twisted is single thread mode,so there is no need to consider thread safety issues.But I use reactor.callInThread to deal long time cost bussiness and send message directly,and the write() is not thread safety,so invoke that error,once I use reactor.callFromThread on send message,it's running right.